# How to properly put two pages onto one using pdfjam?

Tags: packages, positioning, printing

I usually want to include two pages onto one in landscape format for printing, and I use *pdfjam* for that. However, what I notice is that it leaves a lot of empty white-space above and below, and it kind of squeezes the pages. For example, let's take the following PDF file: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/224.pdf

Now, if I run the following command, the produced PDF has a lot of empty space:

```
pdfjam 2019-224.pdf --nup 2x1 --suffix 2up --landscape --outfile temp.pdf
```

How can I make sure that the empty spaces above and below are minimized? I want to make sure that it uses most of the page instead of leaving unnecessarily a lot of margin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To understand what's going on here , just add option `--frame true` (just for testing). E.g:

`pdfjam 2019-224.pdf --nup 2x1 --suffix 2up --landscape --frame true  --outfile temp.pdf`

[image]

Now you see that the top and bottom margins are due to the width of the original PDF.

What you can do is to trim the left and right margins of the original PDF by using the `--trim` option. E.g.:

`pdfjam 2019-224.pdf --nup 2x1 --suffix 2up --landscape --frame true --trim '15mm 0mm 15mm 0mm'  --outfile temp.pdf`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works good. Is there also an option to kind of stretch the text, like reduce even a little bit the white space from below and top? I guess that's paper specific and playing with trim for top and bottom will mess things up, or?

Comment: The relevant length for calculating the scaling factor is either the width or the height of the page. In your case it was the width. And even after trimming 15mm from left and right the width is still the relevant length for the scaling factor. Thus the scaling factor will not change if you trim top and bottom too. Only if you trim the width far enough, say 25 mm in your example, will the height of the page become the relevant length for calculation the scaling factor. And then it makes sense to trim top and bottom too. I'd say just give it a try and use option --frame to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pdfcrop` first, e.g.,

```
$ pdfcrop 2019-224.pdf
PDFCROP 1.40, 2020/06/06 - Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Heiko Oberdiek, Oberdiek Package Support Group.
==> 42 pages written on `2019-224-crop.pdf'.
$ pdfjam 2019-224-crop.pdf --nup 2x1 --suffix 2up --landscape --outfile temp.pdf
```

Comment: Using pdfcrop it is important to do the cropping with the `--bbox` option. Without it, each page might (will) have a different page size. Especially the first page of many papers will probably be smaller. This will produce astonishing results because pdfjam (and pdfpages) are using the first page (by default, but can be changed) to calculate the correct scaling factor.

Comment: @AndreasMatthias, I think your `--trim` option is much nicer.